# get only part of domain from document.domain

Tags: javascript

If i get say x.y.z.com from document.domain, how to get only z.com out of it in java script? > Should i use regexp? Please suggest. Thanks in advance! I have to set it as below in sample java script function. I cannot hard code it.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>domain</title>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function test(){    
domain="z.com"; //set domain here
}
</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#E7E7E7" onload="test()">
</body>
```

Java script code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this construction:

```
document.location.host.split('.').splice(-2, 2).join('.')
```

**UPD**
For example use `document.location.host` = `'new2.new.mail.domain.com'`
Function `split('.')` splits `document.location.host` by `.` into `Array` = `['new2', 'new', 'mail', 'domain', 'com']`
Function `splice(-2, 2)` deletes 2 elements from the end of previous array and return it like `Array` = `['domain', 'com']`
Last `join('.')` function joins by `.` prevoius array into string = `domain.com`
Profit!

**UPD 2**
First of all see the reference to the [Array.splce() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
```

First argument in splice function is a position from which you will be delete elements, in your example `-2` means that its the second element from the end of the array.
Second argument in splice function - how many elements we will be delete, in your code `2` means delete 2 elements.
In the second example first arguments in splice means index of the element from which you want to delete elements. In javascript array indexes begins from 0 and `fruits[2]` will be the `Apple`.

Comment: This worked for me! But, can you please explain me what exactly are we doing here?

Comment: Sure, see **UPD** section

Comment: I tried this to understand splice
First Time
 var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
 fruits.splice(-2,2);
 var x=document.getElementById("demo");
 x.innerHTML=fruits;
Second Time
 var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
 fruits.splice(2,2);
 var x=document.getElementById("demo");
 x.innerHTML=fruits;
Both times it prints Banana,Orange. Why is it so?

Comment: See **UPD 2** section.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to like `'x.y.z.com'.replace(/^.*?(\w+\.com)$/, '$1')`

Comment: I tried this with the domain like preview16.aryot.com and it returns t.com. I want aryot.com to be returned

Comment: You are right :). Have updated the regex to be non-greedy looking for the prefix

Comment: Thank you :) it works! Can you please explain this regex for my understanding?